# How to count number of rows that follow a condition in two columns in pandas using Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with multiple columns, 4 of which are `car`, `company_name`, `id`, and `status`. Each `car` has an associated `company_name` and `status`, and each `company_name` is linked to a unique `ID`. One possible status is `Rented` and I'm trying to count the number of `Rented` cars for each company (in a new column called # of Rented Cars) and I have been trying to use their unique ids to do so.

I have tried using `groupby` and apply but to no success.

```
df['# of Rented Cars'] = df.groupBy('unique_id')['status'].apply(lambda x: (x=='Rented').sum())
```

Using the following table as an example, you can see the values I want in the # of Rented Cars Column:

[image: table]

But using the code above I just get the value Nan for all values in the last column.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `transform`

```
df['# of Rented Cars'] = df.groupBy('unique_id')['status'].transform(lambda x: (x=='Rented').sum())
```

or without `lambda`

```
df['# of Rented Cars'] = df['status'].eq('Rented').groupBy(df['unique_id']).transform('sum')
```